# How to show all product image in product listing/list.phtml

Tags: magento-1, product-images

I want to show all product images in product listing page(list.phtml file).

So to do so I've done following in list.phtml

```
var_dump($_product->getMediaGalleryImages());
```

But it returns with `NULL`.

Another way I found is as following

```
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api');
$mediaItems = $mediaApi->items($_product->getId());
foreach ($mediaItems as $image) {
    echo $image['file'] ."<br>";
}
```

But it return me half path like 
                                                                `/p/a/pawo.jpg`.

So is there any better way to get all product images(Gallery) in product listing page??

**NOTE :** I also need to resize image like we do as following.

```
 <img id="product-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(FALSE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize,$_imgSize); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below code. You canget path using catalog helper

```
echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $image['file']) ."<br>";
```

From this code you can get cache path also.

Comment: What is `$image` here? I am new to Magento Extension Development.

Answer (score 2):

In the second method you are getting proper path, just you have to add media path of catalog product like ::

```
$mediaPath = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/product'
```

The proper solution is :

```
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api');
$mediaItems = $mediaApi->items($_product->getId());
foreach ($mediaItems as $image) {
   echo $mediaPath.$image['file'] ."<br>";
}
```

In first method you have to load product first like :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
var_dump($product->getMediaGalleryImages());
```

To resize use :

```
<img id="product-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image',$image['file'])->constrainOnly(TRUE)->keepAspectRatio(FALSE)->keepFrame(FALSE)->resize($_imgSize,$_imgSize); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>
```

Comment: Which one will be great considering performance??

Comment: I think product load in list page will take load time so its better to use second solution. It will load only product media not all attribute of product.

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention is I want to resize image as well